# how to display iframe from html text in angular 2

Tags: angular

the goal is to render static html document inside an iframe

```
content = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`<iframe>${x.html}</iframe>`)

<mat-dialog-content [innerHTML]="content"></mat-dialog-content>
```

for some reason angular does not like this because the content is injected as text after the html tag

EDIT: html content to be rendered

```html
<html><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type"><style type="text/css">ol{margin:0;padding:0}table td,table th{padding:0}.c3{color:#000000;font-weight:400;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:11pt;font-family:"Arial";font-style:normal}.c2{padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;line-height:1.15;orphans:2;widows:2;text-align:center}.c0{background-color:#ffffff;max-width:468pt;padding:72pt 72pt 72pt 72pt}.c1{font-weight:700}.title{padding-top:0pt;color:#000000;font-size:26pt;padding-bottom:3pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.15;page-break-after:avoid;orphans:2;widows:2;text-align:left}.subtitle{padding-top:0pt;color:#666666;font-size:15pt;padding-bottom:16pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.15;page-break-after:avoid;orphans:2;widows:2;text-align:left}li{color:#000000;font-size:11pt;font-family:"Arial"}p{margin:0;color:#000000;font-size:11pt;font-family:"Arial"}h1{padding-top:20pt;color:#000000;font-size:20pt;padding-bottom:6pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.15;page-break-after:avoid;orphans:2;widows:2;text-align:left}h2{padding-top:18pt;color:#000000;font-size:16pt;padding-bottom:6pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.15;page-break-after:avoid;orphans:2;widows:2;text-align:left}h3{padding-top:16pt;color:#434343;font-size:14pt;padding-bottom:4pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.15;page-break-after:avoid;orphans:2;widows:2;text-align:left}h4{padding-top:14pt;color:#666666;font-size:12pt;padding-bottom:4pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.15;page-break-after:avoid;orphans:2;widows:2;text-align:left}h5{padding-top:12pt;color:#666666;font-size:11pt;padding-bottom:4pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.15;page-break-after:avoid;orphans:2;widows:2;text-align:left}h6{padding-top:12pt;color:#666666;font-size:11pt;padding-bottom:4pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.15;page-break-after:avoid;font-style:italic;orphans:2;widows:2;text-align:left}</style></head><body class="c0 doc-content"><p class="c2"><span>Bla </span><span class="c1">bla</span><span class="c3">&nbsp;bla</span></p></body></html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you need Iframe all time in HTML then you can try below approach:

```
content = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(x.html)

<mat-dialog-content><iframe [srcdoc]="content"></iframe></mat-dialog-content>
```

Comment: thanks for answering, indeed it works but inline css styles are ignored

Comment: Can you please share example html?

Comment: the html to be rendered is an google docs file exported as html. I updated the question with a snippet

Comment: @dsl400 I have setup codesandbox example here and its working fine for me, please check this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-resonance-4pddn0?file=/src/app/app.component.ts